# How to convert string to current date in java?

Tags: java

How can I convert a String like this "Thu Apr 16 16:45:48 'CST' 2015" in a Date but in the current Date format, like this "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"

Answer (score 4):

```
String dateString = "Thu Apr 16 16:45:45 'CST' 2015";
DateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date theDate = dateF.parse(dateString);
```

Edit:
There should not be any ' surrounding the CST. 
You should also add another parameter to the SimpleDateFormat constructor: Locale.your_time_region.
Also make sure you handle the ParseException thrown by the parse function.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).